# Submit button stops working in rails when using javascript to validate input fields when using form_tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, validation

I am doing the validation on the view page itself, because I am not storing this in the database. Therefore, I cannot use model validation for this. I had to resource to using JavaScript to check for validation to make sure the user is not submitting wrong values or submitting empty fields that are required. This does prevent the user from submitting wrong inputs, but after the error alert box pops up it disables the submit button for some reason and the user cannot fix his mistake and try to submit again.

**feedback.html.erb**

```
<script>
  function validateForm() {

    if (document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value == null || document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value == "") {
      alert("Name must be filled out");
      return false;
    }
    if (document.forms["myForm"]["message"].value == null || document.forms["myForm"]["message"].value == "") {
      alert("Message must be filled out");
      return false;
    }
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos+2 || dotpos+2 >= x.length) {
      alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-content">
    <%= form_tag send_feedback_forms_path, name:'myForm', onsubmit:'return validateForm()' do %>
        <%= label_tag 'name', 'Name:', class: 'control-label' %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'name', nil, placeholder: 'Enter Your Name', class:'form-control' %>
        <%= label_tag 'text', 'Email:', class: 'control-label'%>
        <%= email_field_tag 'email', nil, placeholder: 'Enter Your Email', class:'form-control' %>
        <%= label_tag 'phone', 'Phone:', class: 'control-label'%> <span style="font-size: small; color: red">(optional*)</span>
        <%= phone_field_tag 'phone', nil, placeholder: 'Enter Your Phone Number', class:'form-control' %>
        <%= label_tag 'message', 'Message:', class: 'control-label' %>
        <%= text_area_tag 'message', nil, placeholder: 'Enter Your Message', class:'form-control' %><br>
        <%= submit_tag 'Submit', class: 'btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole reason you're resorting to javascript is based on the premise that you can't use Models because they're not being persisted to a database and so I felt compelled to give you a Rails alternative.  What you're looking to do is setup a "form model".  This allows you to use all the Rails magic without needing any data backed by a table.  All this requires is making a class, adding some virtual attributes, and then including some Rails modules and you're good to go.  Example below:

```
#app/models/new_user.rb
class NewUser
  include ActiveModel::Model  #This gives you validations and all the rails magic a standard table backed model would
  attr_accessor :email   #This gives you read&write methods for your virtual attribute
  attr_accessor :username

  validates :username, :email, presence: true  #standard rails validations

  def initialize(params={})
      self.username = params[:username]
      self.email = params[:email]
  end
end
```

Now in your controller you need to instantiate the object for the view:

```
    def new
       @new_user = NewUser.new
    end
```

Then in the action that the form submits to, since you're not persisting any data you need to just check that it is valid:

```
def create
  @new_user = NewUser.new(email: params[new_user][:email], username: params[:new_user][:username])
  if @new_user.valid?
           #passed validation so do whatever
  else
     #flash some errors etc
  end
end
```

As you continue to develop larger Rails apps. you'll notice that one model may have to deal with many different forms on different pages all expecting different amounts of data. It's at this point that handling all of the validations for all of the many different forms for one model becomes a disaster.  The method above will allow you to organize your code on a form by form basis and not be restricted.

Comment: I thought you had to had a database to use a model. That makes sense. Thank you!